# How do I change config options (minWidth) on the fly in ExtJS 4.0.5?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, single-page-application

I have an Ext.window.Window Component with minHeight and minWidth set in the config options like so:

```
config: {
         minWidth: 860,
         minHeight: 580
        },
```

Now I want to change these properties in a function like so:

```
Ext.getCmp('x').setMinWidth(1280);
```

but that Setter doesn't exist in ExtJS 4.0.5 yet. (In later versions it does)

I also tried doing this:

```
Ext.getCmp('x').config.minWidth = 1280;
```

but it also doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create some sencha fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In ExtJS [Window](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window) you can use `updateLayout` method after changing config value.

**updateLayout** updates this component's layout. If this update effects this components ownerCt, that component's updateLayout method will be called to perform the layout instead. Otherwise, just this component (and its child items) will layout.

Here I have created and [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2980) demo. It will show how is working, Hope this will help you to solve your problem or achieve your requirement.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    minWidth: 400,
    minHeight: 300,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [{ // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
        xtype: 'grid',
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        border: false,
        store: {
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: {
                'items': [{
                    'name': 'Lisa',
                    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-111-1224"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Bart',
                    "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1234"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Homer',
                    "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1244"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Marge',
                    "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1254"
                }]
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }],
    }, {
        xtype:'button',
        text: 'Update min height and width with Random Number',
        height: 40,
        margin: 10,
        width:'100%',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function () {
            /**
             * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
             * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
             */
            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }

            var num = getRandomInt(300, 600),
                wind = this.up('window');
            wind.minHeight = num;
            wind.minWidth = num;
            wind.updateLayout();
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Resizing the window is limited to the new minWidth & minHeight dimensions, however the "resize preview" (the dashed line you see when holding the window border and dragging inwards) still let's you drag until the old "min"-dimensions. Though when releasing the left mouse button the window size snaps to the new "min"-dimensions.
I'm sorry if I can't explain the issue clear enough. It's quite a big project so it's a bit hard for me to break it down to a fiddle.

Comment: I just checked, and it happens in your sencha fiddle too. After increasing the minWidth or minHeight, the resize preview still lets you drag further.

Comment: sorry but actually i didn't get you.

Comment: I mean this dashed blue line that indicates how far you resize. 

https://imgur.com/a/2SYf8

It goes further than the actual minWidth/minHeight. (Up to the old minWidth/minHeight to be exact)

Comment: Ok I need to check in further details then will update you